# select dropdown option set to default when click reset button on react js

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a dropdown select filter and there is a reset button, so I want to reset data whenever I click on it.
this is my select dropdown where I am filtering data

```
<select
    className={style.input}
    name="categoryId"
    onChange={e => handleCategory(e.target.value)}
>
    <option value="" disabled selected>
        Select A Categtory
    </option>
    {props.category_list && props.category_list.length > 0
        ? props.category_list.map((item, index) => (
              <option value={item.categoryId}>{item.categoryName}</option>
          ))
        : null}
</select>
```

this is onChange method of select

```
 const handleCategory = (value) => {
    setErrorMsg(null);
    setCategoryID(value);
    props.getSubCategoryList(value);
  };
```

and this is a reset button, I tried to make

```
  const handleReset = (value) => {
    setReset(true);
    setCategoryID('');
    setSkillID('');
    setLocationId('');
    props.getSubCategoryList(1);
  };
```

but the problem is when I click on reset it resets, but the value doesn't change to default one in options also if I change it in  {item.categoryName} then three same values appear under options. hope this information is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the selected value to `select` element.

1. Provide `categoryID` as a prop to your component.
2. Set it as the `value` property of `select`.

```
<select
    ...
    ...
    value={props.categoryID}
    onChange={e => handleCategory(e.target.value)}
></select>
```

Comment: @How to Program, check this out !!